# What is the difference between unobstrusive validation and the default provided in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, validation

I've been reading a lot of posts about unobtrusive validation. I'm trying to understand the difference (if any) between what visual studio provides in an empty MVC3 template and including the jquery.unobtrusive js files. At present this is what my inputs in the source look like

```
    <input class="input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Surname field is required." id="Surname" name="Surname" type="text" value="" />
```

Is this unobstrusive validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `data-` attributes in your HTML syntax, it looks like your page is enabled for unobtrusive client-side validation.

With the traditional client-side validation javascript for the controls to be validated are generated at the server-side and passed on along with the HTML in the Response to the browser.
Hence in addition to the HTML content there will be inline script data embedded within `<![CDATA[ ]]>`

However with unobtrusive client-side validation instead of emitting inline javascript, it makes use of HTML5 compatible [Data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) 
ASP.NET MVC 3 make use of jQuery for unobtrusive client-side validations. `data-` attributes will be manipulated from jQuery functions defined within `jquery.unobtrusive js`

By default unobtrusive mode is turned off in ASP.NET MVC 3. To make use of this you will need to enable both client-side validation & unobtrusive javascript validation.

This can be set in web.config

```
<configuration>    
  <appSettings>        
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>        
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes it looks like you use unobtrusive validation. To have a deeper understandig of what it is and how it works please have a read http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

MVC outputs the data-* attributes and jquery provides the actual client side implementation if looking for those attributes.

http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/02/unobstrusive-javascript-in-mvc-3-helps.html